# printing integer and char using the same argument in c

Tags: c

I have an assignment to implement a board game. I come up with an idea to print integer and char using the same statement for example,

```
int main() {
    char c[2];
    
    c[0]=1;
    c[1]='X';
    
    for (int i = 0;i<=1;++i) {
        printf("%d", c[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

this is not working as I have integer and char in the array. how could i modify this to just use one for loop?

**EDIT:**

I am trying to implement a noughts and crosses game. So I display my board as

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

and whenever a player put down a X or O at a position, I want to display my board for example,

```
1 X 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Comment: Instead of doing really strange things, use an array of struct, each containing one character and one integer.

Comment: `printf("%d%c", c[0], c[1]);` no loops

Comment: OT: you should indent your code properly

Comment: You cannot store different types in a `char[]` array. `c[0]` contains the `char` value 1 which corresponds to CTRL+A, and `c[1]` contains the ASCII code of the character `'X'` which is the value 88. You cannot detect later how to interpret the value if you don't store additional information somewhere that will tell you that want `c[0]` to be printed as a number and `c[1]` as a character.

Comment: You should read a book or follow a tutorial or something. You're on the wrong track here.

Comment: How is the loop supposed to know which elements should be printed as an integer and which as a char?

Comment: thank you all! the thing is we don't know where the character will locate in the array. So I don't know when to use %d and when to use %c. is there a way to go around this no matter what the datatype comes up in the array?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more information. What are the possible number range and character range you want to store? Or in other wording: List the possible values (nubers and characters) that you want to store.

Comment: thank you again. I just add some information. appreciate any comments

Comment: Just print `char` and use `'1'` (character for number 1, equals to number 49) instead of just 1.

Comment: Before the edit it was a typical [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). aragae's comment is the  answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can just print chars. Since your digits are always 1 to 9 you can use chars '1' to '9' (49 to 57) instead.

It's not exactly a code you'd be writing in production, but it's a nice case of a little puzzle and what you can do with C.

```
int main() {
    char c[2];
    
    c[0]='1';
    c[1]='X';
    
    for (int i = 0;i<=1;++i) {
        printf("%c", c[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I've slightly modified your code to make it clear how that might work.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing to mistakes here.

- You're using `c[0]=1;` instead of `c[0]='1';`. You want the character 1 and not the number 1.
- You're using `printf("%d` instead of `printf("%c`. You want to print a character and not a number.

Here is some example code to achieve what you want:

```
void print_board(char *board) {
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        printf("%c ", board[i]);
        if(i % 3 == 2)
            printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void init_board(char *board) {
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++) 
        board[i] = '1' + i;
}

int main(void) {
    char board[9];

    init_board(board);
    print_board(board);

    board[2] = 'X';
    print_board(board);

    board[5] = 'O';
    print_board(board);        

    init_board(board);
    print_board(board);
}
```

The above is not really production code. But it's enough to get you going.

Output:

```
$ ./a.out 
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 

1 2 X 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 

1 2 X 
4 5 O 
7 8 9 

1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't work as intended as you're mixing up two distinct data types. `int` and `char` are not the same type of element. They don't even have the same size; the size of `char` is defined as 1, and the size of `int` varies by implementation, but is usually 4 or 8. So your array will not even be able to hold `int`s. When you say:

```
c[0] = 1;
```

what is actually happening is that the array stores the `char` with the [ASCII value of 1](http://www.asciitable.com), which is the "Start of Heading" character.

To do what you want, do not use the `int` type at all. Use `char` throughout. That is, write something like this:

```
c[0] = '1';
```

Putting the `'1'` in single quotes makes it a `char`, not an `int`. You can use this to fill your 2D array and then make replacements with `'X'` and `'0'` when needed.